# Excel VBA Macro to copy worksheet and count + 1

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to create a macro that is on worksheet `overview`. This worksheet should be copied and renamed into `Test 1`. If I go back to the overview worksheet and start the macro again the newname of the `ws` should be `Test 2` and so on.

I already tried Solutions with `Count` and if then but it is not working. Currently it runs once and then it says the `ws` already exists:

```
Sub CopyWs()

Dim NewName As String

ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=ActiveSheet

NewName = "Test  " & WsNo + 1

WsNo = WsNo + 1

ActiveSheet.Name = NewName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I had a similar issue in the past, and I used the following methodology to solve it.

```
    Dim worksheetName As String
    worksheetName = "Test 1"
    worksheetNumber = 2
    CheckName:
        For Each ws in Sheets
            ' If the desired worksheet name exists
            If ws.name = worksheetName Then
                ' Change the worksheetName to be Test x+1 and increment worksheetNumber
                worksheetName = "Test " & worksheetNumber
                worksheetNumber = worksheetNumber + 1
                GoTo CheckName ' return to the CheckName label and start again
            End If
        Next ws
```

Essentially, what we are doing is looping through every worksheet in the current workbook, and checking if any of them have the same name as the one we want to insert. If they do, we change the name to a new one and check again; if not, we have our new name.

EDIT: Also, I would suggest putting the above code inside a Function that takes the sheet name as an argument, so you can change the desired name easily, like so:

```
    Function worksheetName(desiredName As String) As String
        Dim worksheetName As String
        worksheetName = desiredName
        ' rest of code follows ...
    End Function
```

And then it can be called like so:

```
    NewName = worksheetName("Test")
```